# Is socket.io web site SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, javascript

I know google bot load javascript and execute it. for example react app can be SEO friendly if I use react router and ...

But does google bot execute websocket (socket.io) and get result and crawl that?

For example if have `/products` route and after socket connect an event with name `product_list` come and I put them in the table.